# Sending UDP packet to dead server

Tags: c, sockets, udp

`sendto()` & `recvfrom()` socket API is used to send a packet over UDP.

We have a scenario where, `Node1`(UDP client program) sending a UDP packet to `Node2`(server which is UP) & `Node3`(server which is down).

---

TCP performs handshake before start and after finishing data communication. UDP doesn't.

So, Does application running on `Node1` fail for a reason that server program on `Node3` is not ready(down) to receive UDP packets?

Comment: UDP packets are send-and-pray. If anyone receives them, great. If no one does, well, that's OK too. Nothing on the receiving end should cause the sender to fail. Of course, the sender might be something like a DNS server, that sends out request packets and expects someone to respond, but still it is in full control--it should be written so that if no response comes, it simply reports that without causing a failure.

Comment: Well yes. That’s what UDP does. You must have considered such possibilities when you designed-in use of fire-and-forget UDP.

Answer (score 1):

It won't fail, the transaction simply won't happen. Having said that, any and all packets that aren't recieved are lost.

Answer (score 1):

UDP protocol doesn't let you know whether the data is transmitted since it doesn't have such a property. There is no any problem flow of the program. In my opinion, it's the case why datagrams are useful.